# Dimples in mesh with edge crease, sub-surf and mirror modifiers

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface, mirror-modifier

The top screen grab is showing the edges creased to 1.0

The bottom pic is in object mode, showing the dimples at the mid-line.

Anybody know how to resolve this (get rid of the dimples)?

[image: dimples]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change modifier stack order to Mirror then Sub-Division.